# Adding element to dom and applying class with jquery doesn't apply css3 transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

First, my demo is here: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeschafe/cUQtq/11/).

I'm trying to add an element to the dom with jquery and then make it do some css3-transition animations.  I'm not sure why it doesn't work the first time it's appended.  I click the button and it appends but when I addClass to the div it doesn't animate it.  It simply just applies the css without animations.

Any idea of why this doesn't work for the `div.addClass('test')` right after the element is appended?

May be the same as [Trigering a CSS3 Transition with adding a class with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715039/trigering-a-css3-transition-with-adding-a-class-with-jquery)

But I'm curious if there was any new solutions to it.  That one didn't seem to really get answered.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion from your article seems to somewhat work, i see your commented out code and it looked like the timeout needed to be lower or it needed to be applied with the class selector and not the variable / div. Really no idea why it works, I just fiddle.

I changed a line in your fiddle to reflect the suggestion from that article.

```
setTimeout(function(){$('.article').addClass('test').removeClass('test2');}, 0)
```